# How does cloud foundry handle process isolation?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Let's say that I setup my own cloud using the open source cloud foundry implementation provided on [cloudfoundry.org](http://www.cloudfoundry.org).  Will each app that I deploy be run as a separate user?  Or is there any of VMWare's virtualization technology in use here?  E.g. would each app run in a separate virtual machine or anything like that?  How can I configure the memory, cpu, and disk resource limits for each app?

Comment: [It's open source](https://github.com/cloudfoundry) so you should be able to answer this question for yourself.

Comment: So no one should ever ask any question about an open source project?  I'm sure I could dig through the source, but it always takes time to get up to speed on a new code base and it would take me quite awhile to figure out where in the code to even begin to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I asked this on the mailing list.](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/topic/vcap-dev/vfhYoEYqsqs/discussion)  Here's the response I got:

If your DEA is configured to run in secure mode, then each app runs as its own user and process isolation is used to protect them.  We are moving toward a model of using linux cgroups http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups when on linux, using the warden cgroup wrappers that are already in our source tree.

VM based isolation for a single app is pretty heavy weight, but we have long term plans to provide this for apps that need/desire it.  (As opposed to the warden/cgroup work which is a near term project)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is related to the open source for cloud foundry, you can try asking your question on https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev

You should get a quick response there!

Comment: Thanks.  I found the forum originally, which they're migrating over to stackoverflow.  Wasn't aware there was a mailing list.