# Security in cloudfoundry

Tags: security, cloud-foundry

As you probably know cloud foundry, is a platform-as-a-service provider in clouds.
Does anybody know the principle of security in this provider?
Does it provide any security in its infrastructure for user at all?
many thanks in advance

Comment: See also this quesiton about isolation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668220/how-does-cloud-foundry-handle-process-isolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry has a service called UAA - User Account and Authentication.

The documentation for the UAA service is here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Authentication and accounts are obviously helpful as a first step, but that doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @JustinCormack The original question was about security for users; it was also asked in 2012, which was prior to CF v2 introducing various new concepts like organisations and spaces.

Security itself has many dimensions, particularly in the cloud: 
- availability of secure protocols
- login, authentication, and SSO (covered in part by the UAA component, which itself can be extended to work with additional security providers)
- encryption
- isolation of application processes via containers etc (handled today in CF by Warden, Docker is under consideration for the future... partly using LXC)